# Burninate [arranging]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tagging

Can we kill [arranging](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/arranging)?

Right now it was used in only 2 questions from last year and a new one just asked, has no wiki and it's quite a generic term... There's already [alignment](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/alignment) and [composition](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/composition), do we really need this tag?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the votes and no comments in the negative, I removed the tag and cleaned up the questions. The tag will be removed from the system after a couple weeks of non-usage.